# What rubygem proxy to use in a maven build?

Tags: maven, dependencies, rubygems, jruby

In my maven build, I use asciidoctor-maven-plugin, which can use pure gem dependencies.

To render diagrams, I use [asciidoctor-kroki](https://github.com/Mogztter/asciidoctor-kroki), which is only available as [a ruby gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/asciidoctor-kroki).

As a consequence, I use the [gem-maven-plugin](https://github.com/torquebox/jruby-maven-plugins) which allow to download gems as maven dependencies. Unfortunatly, since the last week, I can no more download the dependency due to the fact that http://rubygems-proxy.torquebox.org/releases is expired. According to [Twitter](https://twitter.com/jruby/status/1216832621000282112), I've found that it could be replaced with http://mavengems.jruby.org/releases. After having tried that url, nothing changed: the dependency still cannot be changed, and I'm stuck with the same error.

Which URL can I use to have my build working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, since all JRuby translating repoitories have expired, I had to rely upon another solution ... which is the [mavengem download](https://github.com/jruby/mavengem) maven plugin.

To configure that plugin, I had to change the declaration of the ruby gems repository:

```
    <repository>
            <id>mavengems</id>
            <url>mavengem:https://rubygems.org</url>
        </repository>
```

And I had to add the plugin to my pom

```
        <extensions>
            <extension>
                <!-- this allows us to download gems -->
                <groupId>org.torquebox.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>mavengem-wagon</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.3</version>
            </extension>
        </extensions>
```

Notice it is added as an extension, to be able to provide supplementary connection protocols.

Once both these configurations changes were done, everything worked correctly.